# R count columns values

Tags: r

Help with R: I need to group by a column and count occurrences of values in a set of columns.

Here is my data frame

```
ID  Ob1 Ob2 Ob3 Ob4
3792    0   0   0   1
3792    0   0   -1  0
3792    1   -2  -1  0
3792    2   -2  -1  0
8060    -1  0   -2  2
8060    -1  0   -3  0
8060    0   0   0   0
13098   0   0   0   0
13098   -1  0   -1  0
13098   0   0   0   0
```

I want to groupby ID and count the values of numbers in Ob1, Ob2, Ob3, Ob4. so my result should look like below;

```
Group   -3  -2  -1  0   1   2
3792        2   3   8   2   1
8060    1   1   2   7       1
13098           2   10
```

I tried

```
table(unlist(df))
```

but I loose the groupby info. I get below

```
-3    -2    -1     0     1     2    46  3792  8060 13098 
 1     3     7    25     2     2    10     4     3     3
```

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` and `tidyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 gather(var, val, -ID) %>%
 select(-var) %>%
 count(ID, val) %>%
 spread(val, n, fill = 0)

     ID  `-3`  `-2`  `-1`   `0`   `1`   `2`
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  3792     0     2     3     8     2     1
2  8060     1     1     2     7     0     1
3 13098     0     0     2    10     0     0
```

Comment: Maybe the same `df1 %>% gather(var, val, - ID) %>% select(ID, val) %>% table`

Answer (score 1):

Using `table` from `base R`

```
table(data.frame(col1 = df1$ID, col2 = unlist(df1[-1])))
#   col2
#col1    -3 -2 -1  0  1  2
#  3792   0  2  3  8  2  1
#  8060   1  1  2  7  0  1
#  13098  0  0  2 10  0  0
```

There is also no need to create a `data.frame`.  The above is done so that the lengths are same (as there is recycling in `data.frame`) and `table` needs arguments to be of same length.  So, a variant of the above should also work well

```
table(rep(df1$ID, ncol(df1)-1), unlist(df1[-1]))
```

---

If we are `unlist`ing the whole dataset, it is just a single `vector`, instead we need two vectors, one for the first column 'ID' and the second for all other columns except the 'ID'

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(3792L, 3792L, 3792L, 3792L, 8060L, 8060L, 
8060L, 13098L, 13098L, 13098L), Ob1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, -1L, 
-1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L), Ob2 = c(0L, 0L, -2L, -2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), Ob3 = c(0L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -2L, -3L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 
0L), Ob4 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)),
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with(reshape2::melt(df1, id.vars = "ID"), table(ID, value))
#       value
#ID      -3 -2 -1  0  1  2
#  3792   0  2  3  8  2  1
#  8060   1  1  2  7  0  1
#  13098  0  0  2 10  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dplyr`. Assume the datafame is called `df`

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(Obs1 = sum(Obs1), Obs2 = sum(Obs2), Obs3 = sum(Obs3), Obs4 = sum(Obs4))
```

Answer (score 0):

This just requires `dplyr`

```
df<-read.table(text="
  ID  Ob1 Ob2 Ob3 Ob4
  3792    0   0   0   1
  3792    0   0   -1  0
  3792    1   -2  -1  0
  3792    2   -2  -1  0
  8060    -1  0   -2  2
  8060    -1  0   -3  0
  8060    0   0   0   0
  13098   0   0   0   0
  13098   -1  0   -1  0
  13098   0   0   0   0
",header=T)
  df
  library(dplyr)
melt(df,id.vars = "ID")%>%
  cast(.,ID~value)
```

Result:

```
Aggregation requires fun.aggregate: length used as default
     ID -3 -2 -1  0 1 2
1  3792  0  2  3  8 2 1
2  8060  1  1  2  7 0 1
3 13098  0  0  2 10 0 0
```